# is it required to call sqlite3_finalize when sqlite3_step fails

Tags: sqlite

I have some case like below

```
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 12,"test",4,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
int retv = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if (retv != SQLITE_DONE) {
   throw "Sql Exception"
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

so my question is, is it required to call sqlite3_finalize before throwing the exception, I am thinking that if any error in the sqlite3_step it will  internally clear the stmt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) says:

> The application must finalize every prepared statement in order to
>   avoid resource leaks

So **yes** you must call `sqlite3_finalize`